# Freshly init array is empty - why?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Newbie here (to C, objective-C, and iOS)...

For this code in my AppDelegate.m, why is the freshly initialized array empty?  Looks to me like I give it some values.  Clue1 etc are are series of UILabels and there are no issues noted by Xcode.  I've been through SO quite a bit and this seems to be the way to do it.  Xcode 4.2.  Thanks!

```
- (id)init {       
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {           
        // Make arrays containing the objects: this is the objective-C way!
       self.clueLabs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: Clue1, Clue2, Clue3, nil];
    }   
    NSLog(@"%@", [clueLabs description]);
    if (!clueLabs || ![clueLabs count]) { // these 2 do m/l the same thing
        NSLog(@"clueLabs is empty!");
    }       
    return self; 
}
```

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not, is clueLabs a retained property? If so, you are over retaining it.

Comment: Yes, ARC is on.  Header file contains "IBOutlet UILabel *Clue1;" and '@property (strong) UILabel *Clue1' for each clue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if Clue1, Clue2 Clue3 are not nils.

Comment: Ah, that might be it.  I declare them, but don't give them any values.  Thanks, I'll try that.  Silly me.

Comment: Can I alloc and init the array with nil objects, then set them to some value in a loop, or must I individually init the UILabels to some non nil value?  1st option much shorter code! EDIT: maybe loop approach is not possible b/c count is zero and can't iterate over an empty array to fill it...

Comment: When you init the array with method *initWithObjects* - they may not be nil. You may create an empty NSMutableArray and fill it with objects later though.

Comment: Thanks, I'm back in business!

Comment: OK, partially back in business.  By init'ing these labels, I'm creating them programatically, but I have already created them via IB.  So essentially I have created a totally new set of labels.  My creation of the new labels is like this: self.Clue1 = [[UILabel alloc] init]; then [Clue1 setText:@""];  Do I need to add something to make Xcode realize these are the same buttons as in the nib/xib?  Thanks.

Comment: In this case, you may move the code that creates the array into viewDidLoad function of the viewcontroller - that is the function that gets called after the loading from xib/nib has ended, and is probably exactly what you're looking for in this case.

Comment: I don't have one of those... probably why I get this msg in the log: Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.  Or perhaps more accurately, I don't seem to have one.  God knows what else I'm missing...  I see that I can add a view controller subclass that will use my xib file... is that the right way to go?  Thanks for helping me so much, still trying to understand both the objective-C paradigm and how the iOS interface works.

Comment: OK, I convinced myself I need to add a view controller subclass and associate it with my existing xib file (and I'll eventually need another one for a second view).  Thx.